# App crashes when assigning a value to sharedState.userDTO inside DispatchQueue.main.async block

Tags: swiftui, timer

I have encountered a crash in my SwiftUI app when executing code inside a DispatchQueue.main.async block. The crash occurs specifically when assigning a value to sharedState.userDTO. Surprisingly, when I comment out this assignment, the app runs without any issues.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    sharedState.userDTO = ret
}
```

To provide more context, sharedState is a shared state object used for data management in my app, and userDTO is a property within that object. The assignment is made inside an asynchronous block to ensure the UI is updated on the main thread.

I have checked that sharedState and userDTO are correctly declared and initialized, and there are no other concurrent operations modifying sharedState.userDTO simultaneously. I have also verified that ret is not nil before assigning it.

I'm unsure what might be causing the crash in this scenario. I suspect there may be a concurrency issue or an incorrect usage of the sharedState object.

Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```swift
//
//  CustomTextField.swift
//  DataMapper
//
//  Created by János Kukoda on 2023. 07. 01..
//

import SwiftUI
struct MyText: View {
    let text: String
    let style: String
    let canEdit: Bool
    let expressionAB: IdentifiableText
    let keyword: Keyword
    
    //let onCommit: (String) -> Void
    
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @State private var editText = ""
    @State private var isContentChanged: Bool = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var sharedState: SharedState
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 4) {
            if style == "constant" {
                TextField("", text: $editText)
                    .frame(width: 200)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .onAppear {
                        editText = text
                    }
                    .onChange(of: editText) { newValue in
                        isContentChanged = true
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: false) { _ in
                            if !isContentChanged {
                                if let ruleInd = sharedState.ruleInd,
                                   let userDTO = sharedState.userDTO,
                                   let teamId = sharedState.teamId,
                                   let transformationId = sharedState.transformationId,
                                   let subTransformationInd = sharedState.subTransformationInd
                                {
                                    print("New value entered 3: \(editText)")
                                    sendToBackend(value: editText, keyPath: ["teams", teamId, "transformations", transformationId, "subTransformations", subTransformationInd, "outputs", 0, "mapRules", ruleInd, "objectrule"] + keyword.keyPath, operation: "setValue")
                                    print(editText)
                                    let newValue = editText
                                    var ret = updateClient(userDTO: userDTO, value: editText, keyPath: ["teams", teamId, "transformations", transformationId, "subTransformations", subTransformationInd, "outputs", 0, "mapRules", ruleInd, "objectrule"] + keyword.keyPath, operation: "setValue")
                                    if let ret = ret {
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            sharedState.userDTO = ret
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            isContentChanged = false
                        }
                    }
            } /*else if style == "variable" {
                Text(text)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .vertical], 4)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            }*/ else {
                Button(action: {
                    print(expressionAB.keyPath)
                    sharedState.ruleKeyPathSegment = expressionAB.keyPath
                    sharedState.expression = expressionAB.expression
                    sharedState.expInd = expressionAB.rowNum
                }) {
                    if style == "keyword" {
                        Text(text).modifier(KeywordStyle())
                    } else if style == "variable" {
                        Text(text).modifier(VariableStyle())
                    } else if style == "constant" {
                        Text(text).modifier(ConstantStyle())
                    } else {
                        Text(text)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

`shareState` is created in the main app file as singleton:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DataMapperApp: App {
    var sharedState = SharedState() // create an instance of SharedState
    
    init() {
        // Set color scheme to dark mode
        UITraitCollection.current = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(sharedState).colorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}
```

and it is declared as `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class SharedState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var teamId: String? = "responsive"
    @Published var transformationId: String?
    //@Published var subTransformationId: String?
    @Published var typeTreeId: String?
    @Published var selectedMenuItem: 
    ...
```

Comment: Show how you declare your `sharedState`, is it a `ObservableObject` class?
 Is it passed from a `@StateObject var sharedState = ...` using `.environmentObject(sharedState)`?
 Did you create it, as the name suggest a singleton as well? Is `userDTO` and  `ret` of the same type?

Comment: Yes, `sharedState` is `ObservableObject ` and passed like `.environmentObject(sharedState)`. It is not "strcit" singleton but behaves like so.

Comment: Just as I thought, you should be using `@StateObject var sharedState = SharedState()` in your `DataMapperApp` 
otherwise `sharedState` is not `observed` by the views hierarchy and will not trigger view updates when it changes.
Note, don't you get a compiler error/warning to say that `self` is required in your `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.sharedState.userDTO = ret }`. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).